# Shell script to login to remote server and execute further commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh

I am automating something with Shell Script. And as a part of this, I need shell script to ssh to a remote server, change the hostname of remote server, modify a folder name keeping its contents as it is, and reboot the server. This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
echo "Connecting to $publicip"
ssh -i ./key.txt root@$publicip 'sudo hostnamectl set-hostname autotest$i.domain.com | sudo mv /etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest.domain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest$i.domain.com | reboot'
```

I can see that the script is able to SSH the server, however as soon as it gets connected I see the below output. And while checking the remote server, the above activities in series are not executed.

```
Connecting to --.--.---.--
Connection to --.--.---.-- closed by remote host.
```

Can someone please help me on this at the earliest.?

Comment: if you are logging in as root, you don't need sudo? further pipe should be replaced by ;

"hostnamectl set-hostname autotest$i.domain.com ;  mv /etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest.domain.com /etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest$i.domain.com ; reboot"

Comment: Or better yet use `&&` instead of `|` or `;`.  That way if one thing fails it doesn't try to do the next and you can check the result of the whole command in `$?`.

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling . If you see my above command, mv command makes use of a variable from the above commands. But it doesnt seem to be working. What I get an error is mv: cannot move '/etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest.domain.com' to a subdirectory of itself, '/etc/letsencrypt/live/autotest.domain.com/autotest.domain.com'
Even set hostname also didnt seem to work, when I checked the other server to see if hostname is changed.